# How to implement a ListView in a Fragment

Tags: listview, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I have the following problem. I have an Activity called OverviewActivity with it's layout which implements some ImageButtons. When I click on the ImageButton "Profile" the OverviewActivity will "lead" me to an Activity called "ProfileActivity_2". There I have implemented three Scrolltabs. The code looks like the following

```
public class ProfileActivity_2 extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_scrolltabs);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterTab(fragmentManager));
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.chat, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_chat:
        Intent mailbox = new Intent(this, MailboxListActivity.class);
        startActivity(mailbox);
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

public static FragmentProfile newInstance(String username) {
    FragmentProfile f = new FragmentProfile();
    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("username", username);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

}

class AdapterTab extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public AdapterTab(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (i == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentProfile();
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        fragment = new FragmentBorrowed();
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        fragment = new FragmentLent();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    String title = new String();

    if (position == 0) {
        return "Profil";
    }
    if (position == 1) {
        return "geliehene Bücher";
    }
    if (position == 2) {
        return "verliehene Bücher";
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

So, everything works fine so far. As you can see I have three tabs where each holds a Fragment which are called FragmentProfile, FragmentBorrowed and FragmentLent. So the first "screen" or the first tab keeps the FragmentProfile. When I change to the second tab (FragmentBorrowed) there are two more tabs in there. The code looks like the following.

```
public class FragmentBorrowed extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_borrowed_tab2, container,
            false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    TabHost tabhost = (TabHost) getView()
            .findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    tabhost.setup();
    Resources res = getResources();

    TabSpec spec1 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.tablabel1));
    tabhost.addTab(spec1);

    TabSpec spec2 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec2.setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.tablabel2));
    tabhost.addTab(spec2);

}
}
```

Now I will come to my actual question. In both of these tabs in FragmentBorrowed I want to implement a ListView for each. So when I click on the first tab there will be a ListView and when I click on the second tab I will get a different ListView. I have tried so many things, watched so many tutorials and read through the forum of stackoverflow how to implement a ListView in a Fragment but I could not find a solution for my problem. I tried to call a new Activity in FragmentBorrowed but that did not work as I expected because the Activity will already start when I click the ImageButton "Profile" which I mentioned before and I want to start the new Activity only when I switch to the second tab (FragmentBorrowed).

Can anybody help me?

PS.: I wanted to show you some images of the application but stackoverflow did not allow it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your ProfileActivity_2 must extend ListFragment. Search for it or reply to me if u want some sample code to do that.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. When I change ProfileActivity_2 to ListFragment, how can I come from the OverviewActivity to the ProfileActivity_2. Second, could you please give me some sample code referring to the ListFragment you suggested? Maybe even with my code from ProfileActivity_2 and FragmentBorrowed? That would be very nice! :)

Comment: What i understood from ur question is that u have an activity Overview Activity which consists of three image buttons. In the click event of Profile image button u have navigated to ProfileActivity_2 where u have used three tabs each containing one fragment. Now in your Fragment Borrowed you are having nested tabs, i.e, two tabs within one tab. Am i right uptil now.

Comment: Now u want ur nested tabs to open two separate fragments containing listviews.

Comment: If i am right in understanding your problem then try this:

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-nested-fragment-tabs-tutorial/                                                                                    If you are OK upto implementing two empty nested tabs under your FragmentBorrowed tab then i will think something that can help u in implementing listviews under these nested tabs.